# java.lang.NullPointerException: while filtering data using QueryDsl

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am using Spring data jpa for creating service. In following code I am using Querydsl  for implementing search filter on grid. But for building name I am not able to filter the grid. I am getting 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: null`.

For grid data is coming from multiple tables. I am not using joining for that. I mapped models classes with each other

```
@Service
public class RoomTransferService {

    @Autowired
    RoomTransferRepository roomTransferRepo;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public List<RoomTransfer> findRoomTransfer(String sStatus, String sBuildName, String deptFrom, String deptTo) {

        QRoomTransfer roomTransfer = QRoomTransfer.roomTransfer;

        JPAQuery<RoomTransfer> query = new JPAQuery<RoomTransfer>(em);

        query.from(roomTransfer);

        // filter the details
        if (sStatus != null) {          
            query.where(roomTransfer.sStatus.eq(sStatus));
        }

        // not filtering
        if(sBuildName !=null) {     

            query.where(roomTransfer.roomDeptMap.room.building.sBuildName.eq(sBuildName));
        }
       List<RoomTransfer> QueryResultRoomTramsfer=query.fetch();
       Return QueryResultRoomTramsfer;
```

**Room class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Room implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "room_seq_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "room_seq_generator", sequenceName = "room_seq")
    @Column(name = "nroom_id")
    public Integer nRoomId;

    @Column(name = "ncampus_id")
    public Integer nCampusId;

    @Column(name = "nbuild_id")
    public Integer nBuildId;

    @Column(name = "ninst_id")
    public Integer nInstId;

    @Column(name = "sfloor")
    public String sFloor;

    @Column(name = "sroom_number")
    public String sRoomNumber;

    @Column(name = "sroom_desc")
    public String sRoomDesc;

    @Column(name = "scomments")
    public String sComments; 

    @Column(name = "daccepted_date")
    public Timestamp dAcceptedDate;

    @Column(name = "ssurveyor")
    public String sSurveyor;

    @Column(name = "narea")
    public Integer nArea;

    @Column(name = "ncrt_code_id")
    public Integer nCRTCodeId;

    @Column(name = "ncmn_room_bln")
    public Integer nCMNRoomBln;

    @Column(name = "nunvalidated_bln")
    public Integer nUnvalidatedBln;

    @Column(name = "sbfr_field")
    public String sBfrField;

    @Column(name = "ntemp_room_id")
    public Integer nTempRoomId;

    @Column(name = "bis_active")
    public Boolean bIsActive;

    @Column(name = "bis_jointuse")
    public Boolean bIsJointuse;

    @Column(name = "sstations_desc")
    public String sStationsDesc;

    @Column(name = "ddeleted_on")
    public Timestamp dDeletedOn;

    @Column(name = "ndeleted_by")
    public Integer nDeletedBy;

    @Column(name = "bis_incluster")
    public Boolean bIsIncluster;

    @Column(name = "bis_service_center_activity")
    public Boolean bisServiceCenterActivity;

    @Column(name = "service_center_comments")
    public String serviceCenterComments;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "nbuild_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Building building;
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? What is null? roomTransfer.roomDeptMap.room.building.sBuildName here are lots of possible null values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NPE that you get is probably related to the limitation of QueryDsl where you cannot exceed four levels.

Your code exceeds four levels.

```
roomTransfer.roomDeptMap.room.building.sBuildName
```

You can read more on [official documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/reference/html_single/#d0e2260) or related [stackoverflow's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381064/why-is-query-dsl-entity-path-limited-to-four-levels).

In the first link there is a solution to overcome this issue using `QueryInit` annotation.

If you do not want to alter your entity class you can perform a join (if possible) with an alias for the first 2 or 3 levels and then use this alias to complete the query.

Comment: I added Room class Can you tell me how I can use `QueryInit`

Comment: Can I use like This `@QueryInit("building.sBuildName")
 @ManyToOne(optional = true)
 @JoinColumn(name = "nbuild_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 public Building building;`

Comment: I haven't used this annotation before but you can try what you are asking above. Because I do not want to change my entity class I always perform a join. So try this: `query.join(roomTransfer.roomDeptMap,someAlias).where(someAlias.room.building...)`. I am not aware of your `RoomTransfer` class so you have to edit join according to your class.